# Vuejs 2.0 single file component, webpack and leaflet maps

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, leaflet

I am using vuejs for a couple of weeks.

Right now, I am trying to implement leaflet maps. So I went to leaflet official site, and there they say I need to prepare my page:

- Include Leaflet CSS file in the **head** section of your document
- Include Leaflet JavaScript file
- Put a div element with a certain id where you want your map to be
- Make sure the map container has a defined height, for example by setting it in CSS.

The problem is that I **do not have** <**head**> section in my document because I use single file components like here:

```
<template>
    <div id="mymap">
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped type="text/css">
    #mymap {height: 180px;}
</style>

<script></script>
```

Where should I include this CSS file then?

Comment: Perhaps use an existing library? https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) in your style section to import the CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "path/to/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"

    #mymap {height: 180px;}
</style>
```

For the script, import the script.

```
<script>
     import Leaflet from 'leaflet'

     ...your code
</script>
```

FWIW, there is an HTML somewhere in your process and you can just add it there. Typically it's index.html or something similar.

Secondly I wouldn't import the CSS into the leaflet component you are trying to create; I would import it into your root component to prevent possibly importing the same CSS more than once. The library I linked in the comment takes this approach [in their example application](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet/blob/master/examples/src/App.vue#L93).

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Vue I suppose you will be using some template with vue-cli to start. And it maked structure like [this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/tree/master/template).

My recommendation is that you use [Extract text Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage) 
and you create a global style file under src `styles.css` where to be able to import this kind of styles. Finally add this line in your `main.js`

```
import './styles.css'
```

Comment: wouldn't this result in the css being loaded in all parent components even if they are not used?